# How can I get an UmbracoHelper in an HttpHandler?

Tags: umbraco8

In Umbraco 7 you could use `UmbracoContext.EnsureContext()` and some trickery to get an `UmbracoHelper` outside of an Umbraco context, such as in an HttpHandler. In Umbraco 8 `UmbracoContext.EnsureContext()` has been removed so how can we do this now?

Specifically I want to get the root node, in my HttpHandler like

```
var helper = CreateUmbracoHelper();
var root = helper.ContentAtRoot().First();
```

But I can't figure out how I might implement `CreateUmbracoHelper()`.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it's pretty simple using the DependencyResolver. Here's what I've got and it works perfectly.

```
var factory = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUmbracoContextFactory>();
using (factory.EnsureUmbracoContext())
{
    var helper = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<UmbracoHelper>();
    var websiteNode = helper.ContentAtRoot().Single() as HomePage;
    // etc
}
```